# Finding elements on a complex website using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning how to scrape with Selenium but I encounter some issues trying to find the elements of more complex websites. I've noticed that on more complex websites the xpath is vaguer and makes selenium couldn't find the element. For example, on this web https://www.nike.com.ar/ when I try to find the xpath or the specific class for the men section it gives me this path: /html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span

so my question is, on this type of website when all the elements have a lot of classes or show the XPath like this, how can I find the elements that want to interact?

PS. All of this is done using selenium on Python.

ive tried

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Chromeservice(
    ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://www.nike.com.ar/')

men = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'flex justify-between pv4 nikear-store-components-0-x-accordionTitleMobile nikear-store-components-0-x-accordionTitleMobile--level-0 nikear-store-components-0-x-accordionTitleMobile--open')
men.click()

time(10)

driver.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would recommend is reading [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) around locators carefully. Understand how each locator works and how to use it.

`By.CLASS_NAME` expects only 1 class name and you've passed it several. If you need more than one class name, you'll need to switch to a CSS selector. Given the HTML

```
<div class="one two three">
```

your CSS selector would look like

```
div.one.two.three
```

if you needed all three classes. In CSS selector syntax, a `.` preceeds a class name.

For more info on CSS selectors:

1. [CSS selectors spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)
2. [Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/blog/selenium-tips-css-selectors)
3. [Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)

I know that "copy XPath" from the dev tools makes it "easy" to create XPaths but generally those XPaths that are created are terrible. They are really long, start at the HTML tag, have many levels, and use a lot of indexes. All that means that even a small change to the page and your locator is going to break.

I tried your XPath locator and it didn't point to anything on the site. Since you mentioned the men's (Hombre) section, I'm assuming you meant the element in the top nav,

```
<a class="nikear-store-components-0-x-itemLinkDesktop nikear-store-components-0-x-itemLinkDesktop--level-0 w-100 no-underline t-small outline-0 db tc link truncate" href="/hombre">Hombre</a>
```

A simple CSS selector will find this link

```
a[href='/hombre']
```

Just make sure you add a wait on complex sites to make sure that the element you are looking for is ready to be interacted with. Use `EC.element_to_be_clickable()` to click an element and `EC.visibility_of_element_located()` to `.send_keys()` or get `.text`.